# Delete ID field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL databases and I have just imported my Access database into MySQL. When I did so, my primary key (ID) filed for one particular table is a bit messed up.

I would like all primary keys to be a number, but there is on that is showing up as a the height of a person. This is not present in the Access database.

I would add a picture but I cannot because I do not have the reputation yet... There is a 5' 7" in the ID place of an actual ID. When I attempt to delete this entry using the command

```
DELETE FROM actor_demographics WHERE ID=5' 7";
```

I am not able to delete the ID key. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM actor_demographics WHERE ID=5' 7";
```

Is MySQL incorrect, it should be

```
DELETE FROM actor_demographics WHERE ID="5' 7\"";
```

Comment: I am receiving the error:
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5' 7""

I get the same result for the second answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely your `ID` column has a stringlike, not numberlike, data type.

Try using a string literal in your `DELETE` statement, thus

```
 DELETE FROM actor_demographics WHERE ID='5'' 7"';
```

Because you need a `'` character in your string constant, double it to escape it.

Comment: I am receiving the error:
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5' 7""

I get the same result for the first answer as well.